# Arrays in PHP seems to drop elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am building an app with complex data which I use arrays for. Some of the data comes direct from fetchs from a postgresql data base and some comes from calculation and processing.

I initally build the array that holds all this and everything goes along fine.

Later during processing I have the following code. This is one section of my code.

```
    foreach ($this -> detailTables as $key => $detTable) {
        foreach ($detTable['columns'] as $key2 => $column) {
            if ($column['isID'] == 't') {
                $detTable['mainid'] = $column['columnName'];
            }
            if ($column['lookupTable'] != '') {
                $select = array('table' => $column['lookupTable'], 'id' => $column['lookupID'], 'disp' => $column['lookupDisplay']);
                $detTable['lookups'][] = $select;
            }
        }
        logw($key . ' mainid 1', $detTable['mainid']);
        logw($key.' lookups 1', $detTable['lookups']);
    }

    foreach ($this -> detailTables as $key => $detTable) {
        logw($key . ' mainid 2', $detTable['mainid']);
        logw($key.' lookups 2', $detTable['lookups']);
    }
```

Basically I am scanning detailTables for and their columns to determine and set values for **mindid** and the **lookups** array

In the second foreach segment I am just logging the values to see if the persist.

My Log file reads as follows.

> columns mainid 1 = columnID
>   array columns lookups 1
>    array 0
>     table = tables
>     id = tableID
>     disp = tableName
>
> tabs mainid 1 = tabID
>   array tabs lookups 1
>    array 0
>     table = tables
>     id = tableID
>     disp = tableName

and the output from the second part reads

> columns mainid 2
>  
>   columns lookups 2
>  
>   tabs mainid 2
>  
>   tabs lookups 2

I cannot figure out why the two log sections are not identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of you structure you need to reset the iteration after the first for each through

```
    }
    logw($key . ' mainid 1', $detTable['mainid']);
    logw($key.' lookups 1', $detTable['lookups']);
}
//reset variables here
foreach ($this -> detailTables as $key => $detTable) {
    logw($key . ' mainid 2', $detTable['mainid']);
    logw($key.' lookups 2', $detTable['lookups']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$detTable` should be a reference. So you should change first line into

```
 foreach ($this -> detailTables as $key => &$detTable) {
```